# MySql get rows from last months same day

Tags: mysql

I want to get records from last month's same day by keeping in mind for days which will be skipped and should be included in next day.

e.g. on 31st of march, february 31 does not exist so it should skip the query and also if i want to get records on april 30 it will give the results as required, but then on 1st of may, 31st of march will be skipped.

Currently, I am using

```
SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE orderdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

How can I tackle this in mysql query?

Sorry if i am not able to communicate my query.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with whatever you are using?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya If i run this query on 1st may, this query will get records of 1st april. right? but in the meanwhile, the query skips 31st of march because 30 april will give records of 30 march and then there is no 31st in april so next date will be 1st may

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, can you guide me with that as i haven't worked with udf before

Comment: you already know you can not get data of 30 Feb or 31 April. So technically you have to do something for these cases. either get records of the previous days which one will available or show result no data found on these cases. for this you have to work on each condition . for this there is no shortcut. find all possible cases and return no data found on these cases. you can do this by using conditions in script code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following logic, which retains a record only if subtracting one month did *not* result in an earlier day value:

```
SELECT *
FROM registrations
WHERE
    orderdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month) AND
    DAY(orderdate) = DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month));
```

Comment: will this work for february too? I mean, after 28 1st march comes and script will skip 29, 30 and 31 of january. In this case, I would like to get the records of these days on 1st of march

Comment: This answer assumes that you want to _skip_ dates like March 31, since February has no such day.  This is what your question implies.  If you want other logic, then please edit your question.

Comment: i have edited the question to add the skipped records of days to very next date/day